# Server with LLMs

Tags: node.js, server, concurrency, openai-api, langchain

I'm currently working on an express server (Node) that uses [LangChain](https://www.langchain.com/) and LLMs([OpenAI](https://openai.com/blog/openai-api)).

To use LangChain or communicate with LLMs, I first need to create an object.

Now, two approaches come across my mind:

1. Creating a local object

```js
router.post("/foo", async (req, res) => {
  const llm = new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0.7, modelName: "gpt-4" });

  // Do something with llm
}
```

2. Creating a global object

```js
const llm = new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0.7, modelName: "gpt-4" });

router.post("/foo", async (req, res) => {

  // Do something with llm
}
```

Due to my lack of backend programming and serving LLM-based applications, which convention should I use?
(I believe it is not limited to LLMs, but sharing modules or objects)

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong; it depends on the requirements.

If you want to maintain the state across multiple requests or the object is consuming significant resources on instantiation, it's better to declare it out of the function's scope. However, as you are working with OpenAI API, I don't think that's the case; this is commonly used for database connections, configurations, etc (singleton pattern).

If you want to keep the state only for individual requests, instantiating inside the function makes more sense. You don't have to worry about the complications of error handling, testing, or memory that a singleton pattern can introduce.

Sorry for not giving you a definitive answer. As a rule of thumb, you can think about how expensive it is to instantiate the class in every call or if reusing the instance improves the efficiency to deserve a singleton.